# JQuery double class :visible selector

Tags: jquery, class, selector, visible

Just a quick one. I am trying to work it the next element that is visible of a class and then select a class contained within it.

The first I retrieve like this.

```
var panelnext = $('.sidewrapper:visible').next();
```

Now to get the class within it I tried this

```
var paneltarget = $('.sidewrapper:visible').next('.panelcontent');
```

That did not work unfortunately. Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean `$('.sidewrapper:visible').next().find('.panelcontent')`？

Answer (score 1):

`$('.sidewrapper:visible').next().find('.panelcontent');`

Answer (score 0):

When you say "within," you probably want [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) (for finding descendant elements) rather than [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), which is for siblings. You may want to combine it with [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) to stop at the first match, if you only want one match.

If you really do mean a sibling, rather than a descendant, you may want [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) (perhaps combined with `:first`) rather than `next`. `next` will match the immediate sibling element if it matches the selector, or nothing; it never goes beyond the immediate sibling (behavior I found surprising when I first encountered it). `nextAll` will search the following siblings for matching elements (and so could skip some non-matches), and of course when combined with `:first` will stop at the first match.